# Access user fields on nodes in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have added some custom fields to my user registration form. Namely First Name and Last Name.

Registered users can write articles and I have created a content type for these articles and a node--article.tpl.php.

What I would like to do is render the two fields from the user registration form (First Name, Last Name) below the title of the article. I can't seem to be able to access this data.
I want the specific names that the user supplies instead of the username supplied at login..which could be totally random.

Any ideas how I could render these fields on the node.tpl?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

remember you can load any user's profile data given their uid so instead of `$account = user_load($user->uid);` you would do a `user_load($authors_uid)`

To be more specific, here's a generic, all purpose function I use that gathers the firstname and lastname user fields and returns them separated by a space.  The return is upper case on the request of my users, but you get the idea.  I'm still in the process of converting my D6 to D7 so the language check may not be necessary.  If I find that it is not, I will edit this response.

```
/**
 * This will return the user's name (first last in caps)
 * @uses user_load()
 * @param int $user_id optional user id to look for
 * @return string
 */
function get_user_name($user_id = 0) {
  global $user;
  $active_user = user_load((($user_id > 0)? $user_id : $user->uid));
  $first_name = $active_user->field_firstname[(($active_user->language == '')? 'und' :    $active_user->language)][0]['value'];
  $last_name = $active_user->field_lastname[(($active_user->language == '')? 'und' : $active_user->language)][0]['value'];    
  return strtoupper($first_name . ' ' . $last_name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When a user logs in to Drupal, that user is loaded so that you can access fields like 'username' and 'email' during the request. However, custom fields that you define are not loaded by default.

What you can do is to implement a preprocess function in your theme. That is, create/edit the file 'template.php' in your theme folder, and add the following pice of code:

```
function [mythemename]_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {

  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);

  $vars['firstname'] = $account['path']['to']['field'];
  $vars['lastname'] = $account['path']['to']['field'];

}
```

What happens now is that each time Drupal is about to display a node, it runs all node variables (such as $title and $content) through your function so that you can alter what you need. However, you can also add more variables. So, what we do is to get the user for the request (might be anonymous with 'uid' set to 0) and load that user's account which holds all fields you define.

Please note that I can't remember how those fields are stored in your account. You need to look that up.

Comment: They'll probably be in `$account->field_firstname[$account->language][0]['value'];`

Comment: This answer explains how to access the *currently logged-in user's* fields, but the original question was asking how to display the *author's* fields.